# Docker doesn't copy new images

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a problem regarding Docker.

When I'm deploying a new version of my app image, the images i have added to the images folder in my wwwroot folder aren't copied..

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-projectjson

WORKDIR /app-src
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish src/Test -o /app

EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

And my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
   app:
    image: <dockeruser>/<imagename>:<tag>
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__Dataconnection: "Host=db;Username=Username;Password=Password;Database=db"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ~/data/images:/app/wwwroot/images
   db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "31337:5432"
    volumes:
      - ~/data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

My current version of docker is:
`Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d` and docker-compose `docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31`
The exact same files (except for the docker-compose version was set to 2 in docker-compose.yml) worked previously on docker version `Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22` and docker-compose version `docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387`

I store my new images in my repos wwwroot/images folder, and then push them to the repo, and then dockerhub automatically builds an image from the new commit. On the server i then pull the new docker-image and run the `docker-compose down -v` command followed by `docker-compose up -d` but the images is not available in the app afterwards.

Disclaimer: This is a project I have overtaken and I'm aware of some of the very old software versions.

Comment: Remove the `~` in front of the `/data/db` if it's in the same directory as compose file and use `./data/db`. Otherwise I think you need to use full path.

Comment: The `volumes:` hides the content of the image with the corresponding content on your host system.  At container startup time, this is in effect a "push" into the container and never the other way around.  If you have updated content in your image, delete the bind mount that hides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images may be in your container image, but since you are doing a bind mount whatever is in your server’s “~/data/images” directory will basically “override/replace” what’s in your image when the container is created.

Try removing the volume from the app service, basically remove this:

volumes:
- ~/data/images:/app/wwwroot/images

The other thing you can try is to manually copy the images to the “~/data/images” directory on the server.

Comment: I guess I have some reading regarding binds and mounts to do. Either way, it worked. Thank you very much sir!
Edit: The removing of the volume from the app service is what worked.